# Progressbar while loading data

Tags: r, progress-bar, loading

i'd like to show a progress bar or anything similar while loading data from a text file in R. 
I found something  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165077/how-do-i-create-a-progress-bar-for-data-loading-in-r) but I can't adapt it to text files. I'm working with relatively big data sizes (over 8m rows, nearly 1-2gb per text file).

Is there anyway with the tcltk package to show a progressbar while loading the data to a dataframe ?  (I'm going to use it in a script file for a backgroung execution. Thus, I'm looking for a *tcltk* package like message box)

Thank you very much !

Laurent

Comment: `data.table::fread` has a progress bar option (`showProgress`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I'd like to use it in a scipt as a batch file, so the objective is to do it in background. That's why i'd like to work with the _tclk_ package if possible.